# FileChooserDialog in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, filechooser

The question is simple: i just want to **open my FileChooserDialog many times as i want**, without re-creating the same widget.

Destroy signal/method is not for me, because **i don't want to destroy the reference to the object**, i just need to **hide the FileChooserDialog**

The problem is that, by this code, i just get the dialog with the the buttons, but nothing else (no paths, no files list, no folders..) just the buttons and a grey blank window.

HERE BELOW THE CODE:

```
self.__file_chooser_dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open..",
                                        None,
                                        gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                        (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                        gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

def file_chooser_event(self, widget, data=None):
        self.__file_chooser_dialog.show_all()
        response = self.__file_chooser_dialog.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            print self.__file_chooser_dialog.get_filename(), 'selected'
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
            print 'Closed, no files selected'

        self.__file_chooser_dialog.hide_all()


self.__load_config=gtk.Button('Carica file di configurazione\n(nome__file.ini)')
self.__load_config.connect('clicked', self.file_chooser_event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [gtk.Widget::hide_on_delete](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--hide-on-delete), which exists for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried multiple ways to let it work.. and you just need to do this edit:

```
self.__file_chooser_dialog.show_all() -----> self.__file_chooser_dialog.show()

self.__file_chooser_dialog.hide_all() -----> self.__file_chooser_dialog.hide()
```

Can you explain me why this works?!